# Minimum recommended user knowledge requirements

Tags: education, new-user, opsec

Cryptocurrency newcomers are disproportionately victims of financial loss both because of trusting dishonest 3rd parties and because of poor OPSEC.

Does Monero have a defined set of minimum recommended user knowledge requirements?

For example is there a list of recommended knowledge requirements (with a link to resources to learn more) available to new Monero users? Such a list could include:

- Difference between a hot wallet and a cold wallet
- Difference between individual control, and 3rd party control of funds
- Importance of strong passwords and avoiding password reuse
- Importance of backups
- Definition of key-loggers and precautions that can be taken to avoid the possibility of them collecting your passwords or mnemonic seeds.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Every user has a different background and intended use case for Monero. There is no officially defined knowledge set that is recommended to all users.

Instead, there are basic [user guides](https://getmonero.org/knowledge-base/user-guides/) and tutorials to help new users choose an appropriate wallet for their needs and get started mining Monero.

Generally, the Monero community advises against the use of exchanges and web wallets for storage of large amounts of Monero. [Security and education](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GJQ5prfNfZQ) are emphasized in importance to new users. Usage over investment is highly emphasized by members of the development team. It is not uncommon for newcomers to be advised [not to buy Monero](https://bitcoinmagazine.com/articles/are-any-altcoins-currenty-useful-no-says-monero-developer-riccardo-spagni-1458743546) if their primary objective is speculation.

It is impossible to anticipate every possible question that Monero users and developers may have. One of the primary goals of this StackExchange site is to create an easily searchable database of common questions and useful answers for the Monero community.

Since Monero development is ongoing, the education effort must continually evolve with the changing technology.